# XCode 9 and iPhone 4s simulator

Tags: simulator, xcode9, iphone-4

After updating my XCode version 9, the iPhone 4S simulator is behaving little weird. Very often the screen dance a little bit and the graphics become distorted and pixelated. Especially when the keyboard pops up and hide, i.e. screen movement.

Are you facing the same problem? Any solution? I am not sure will it be same in the actual devices.

Comment: some research from so, came to know that, it will disappear if we use iOS 8.4. And the problem also retains in devices with the same config, iOS 8.1 and iPhone 4s.